# Sync Objects and Database Data EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an app with EF Core which syncs/seeds data at the app start configured in an object structure to the SQL Server database.

At the moment this is done in a manual way. For each sub object you have to write code like:

1. Load DB data
2. Compare with data configured in the object structure
3. Remove not needed data
4. Add new data
5. Save changes

Is there any better way to do something like this? Or a library for data syncs?

Regards

Comment: EF Core isn't a cache or sync library. A DbContext isn't meant to be long-lived either. Whatever you want to do yes, there are suitable ways to do it. What *do* you want to do ? What do you mean `data sync`? It's one thing to cache some lookup data on multiple clients and update it once in a while, another thing to retrieve data for offline processing. Mapping query results to objects is the easiest part of the problem.

Comment: What kind of application? Web, desktop? SignalR can push changes to clients but that won't work with mobile/occasionally-connected applications. For load balanced web apps Redis can be a better option than locally caching changes. .NET Core's distributed caching middleware could be a good alternative